# if/elsif number is divisible by 3

Tags: ruby

I am asking the user to input a number and evaluate that number to see if it's divisible by 3. 
this is my code

```
positive_integer = gets.chomp
if positive_integer % 3 == 0
  puts "#{positive_integer} is divisible by 3"
elsif
  puts "#{positive_integer} is not divisible by 3"
end
```

But for some reason when I input 9, 30, or any number that IS divisible by three I get "#{positive_integer} is not divisible by 3" output.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Your variable is a string, convert it to a number.

Comment: Try adding `positive_integer.class` after the chomp. That variable is a string, and not an Integer. Change the first line to `gets.chomp.to_i`

Comment: yes worked thank you so frigin much!

Answer (score 4):

your variable positive_integer is a string. convert it into integer by

```
  positive_integer = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: Btw. you don't need to call `String#chomp` in this case.